# Logins for "default" user accounts?

Tags: ssh, security

On a server I am accessing with SSH I checked the auth.log and it is mostly login tries for invalid users or root, however occasionally there are login attempts for the accounts www-data, sshd and so on, is it an issue to deactivate ssh for these accounts?

Are they even accessible by default?

GOT THE ANSWER FROM THE OTHER QUESTION:

it is not an issue since these accounts do not have a password by default and ssh does not allow empty passwords by default it is fine as long as I do not mess with either of those.

Comment: It depends on the OS. But very likely, the answer is, that they are not accessible. 1. `sshd_config` has by default set `PermitEmptyPasswords no`  and 2. in `/etc/passwd`, they have by default `/usr/sbin/nologin` or `/bin/false` set as login shell. To prevent such random internet noise, you might want to change the `ssh` port to some high number.